# Domain with vanishing class group is PID

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I'm looking for a reference containing a proof of this statement:

Let $R$ an integral domain. 
Then if $R$ has vanishing [class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) iff it is PID.

Comment: That’s wrong without assuming anything more on $R$ (eg, ring of integers in a number field). An integral domain with vanishing class group is a PID, a strictly stronger notion than a UFD.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was implicitely thinking about Dedekind domains. That is I was looking for the statement you quoted: intergral domain with vanisking class group is PID! I modify the question!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, are you requiring that the domain is Dedekind? If not, I think you should be more precise about your definition of the class group.

Edit: Whoops, I see you're looking for a reference. Many introductory algebraic number theory and commutative algebra books have it, but I think it's a good exercise to do yourself if you're really curious about the proof -- it's not too hard!

Comment: Isn't this immediate from the definitions? The class group is the ideals modulo the principal ideals. So, the class group is trivial if and only if all ideals are principal. What subtleties am I missing here?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: No, I not require DD. The definition for class group I'm using is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group: $J/P$ with $J$ group of fractional ideals of the ring of integers of $K=Frac(R)$ and $P$ the subgroup of principal ideals. Reading the definition of fractional ideals I see not problem to interpret ideals of $R$ also as "fractional ideals". Naively I would say that here we are done, since if fractional ideals are principal then also the ideals of $R$. Is it really so simple or do I missing some point?

Comment: ok I see it now. It is indeed immediate, sorry.